# TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I try to make a simple CRUD application on node.js using express.js. I try to connect to DB, but I have an error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`. Part of my code:

app.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/notepad');

var app = express();

app.get('/users', routes.userlist);

// mongoDB
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   req.db = db; // this is setting up db property to request
   next();
});
```

routes/index.js

```
exports.userlist = function (req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('usercollection'); // error in this line
collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
    res.render('userList', {
        "userlist": docs
    });
});
};
```

I think the instanse of DB is not setted or it's not available in other file. How to solve this?

Comment: `var express = require('express');` i guess.

Comment: @limelights, yes, this line is present

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening. You can't attach a database to a request like that. You need to re-require it in all of your files and establish a connection to it.

Comment: @limelights, yes. you are right. I removed this: var db = req.db; and 'var' in var db = monk('localhost:27017/notepad'); thank you

Comment: actually, you can. and it's better to have one persistent connection to the database for your app than reconnecting for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.use` should be written before your `app.get`. The `app.get` is called first by Express.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/notepad');

var app = express();

// mongoDB
// Do all your "pre-route" use() functions first
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   req.locals.db = db; // this is setting up db property to request
   next();
});

app.get('/users', routes.userlist);
```

In your routes...

```
var db = req.locals.db; // Instead of req.db
```

Or even better...

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/notepad');

var app = express();

app.locals.db = db;

app.get('/users', routes.userlist); // Access it using req.locals.db
```