# Cannot call method 'get' of undefined using mongodb with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I follow a tutorial and have no clue what's wrong. There's no error in my cmd at all. When I open localhost:3000 I saw this error Cannot call method 'get' of undefined and couldn't load the post in my posts collection.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');

/* Homepage blog posts */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var db = req.db;
  var posts = db.get('posts');
  console.log(posts)
  posts.find({},{},function(err,posts){
    res.render('index',{
        "posts":posts
    });
  });
});
```

My jade

```
block content
    if posts
        each post, i in posts
            h1=post.title
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887849/typeerror-cannot-call-method-get-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem, 
You need to first attach db to req object then use it. Place this function before all routes.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // open connection
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

then use it in route.

var dbs = req.db;
```

Otherwise simple is, remove this line and run your app.

```
var db = req.db;
```

complete code

```
var express = require('express');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');

var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var dbPost = req.db;
  var posts = dbPost.get('posts');
  console.log(posts)
  posts.find({},{},function(err, posts){
    res.render('index',{
        posts: posts
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: your complete code is my index.js? I got app is not defined

Comment: kindly recheck your code, i have tested my code on my system before placing it here. make sure, you have installed all dependencies and also created app object by  doing var app = express();

Comment: I got this error     at app.use.res.render.message (C:\wamp\www\node_blog\app.js:81:13)

Comment: kindly put your code on pastebin and place link here

Comment: weird why not found, hmm

Comment: can you paste full error? because line 81 is   `next(err);` which go to next function and try to find error page from views directory. is error page exist?

Comment: Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (C:\wamp\www\node_blog\app.js:81:13)

Comment: paste full error with stack. it seems that you are trying to access route which does not exist. also tell me is there error page exist in app?

Comment: this function should come up before all routes `// Make our db accessible to our router
```// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);```

Comment: yes it worked!! thanks so much!! so actually I don't have to change anything on my index.js (route) right? it's just missed configured on the app.js

Comment: But one thing I don't understand, why we assign to var db with this
`var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');` and then with this
  `var db = req.db;` in route.get again??

Comment: it is for easiness. because we want to access it in other routes also. otherwise we have to define db connection with some other logic to be accessible in all routes.